# How to configure sonata user bundle to get the result in the documentation

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I want to have the same result in documentation Sonata symfony but look what I have after debugging some error. If u have any idea how to solve these errors please help me:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the result after clearing the cache and generating assets?

symfony 2 :

```
php app/console cache:clear
php app/console assets:install --symlink web
php app/console assetic:dump
```

symfony 3 :

```
php bin/console cache:clear
php bin/console assets:install --symlink web
```

Comment: the probléme not about the cache or even assets , i think i miss some modules or some configuration or some bundle , because i get directlly into the userbundle instalation , without even look to other section of documentation ....any why if u have the section that i should implement can u list them for me ..by order..thx

Comment: First of all you need to read about sonata admin bundle itself, then there is no order for media, user, taxonomy or other bundle